# where to find the _jsp.java and _jsp.class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

In normal spring mvc it will be available inside the tomcat server jar
where to find the _jsp.java and _jsp.class in spring boot project.

Answer (score 2):

For Normal Spring mvc application the _jsp.java and _jsp.class is available in the tomcat server jar where our application is deployed.

But in case of Spring boot the tomcat server is embedded and in spring boot project the _jsp.java and _jsp.class will be found in the below location(this is for windows OS).

C:/users//Appdata/local/Temp/1/tomcat.<port number(eg:8080)>.some_number/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_***INF/jsp/view/

the path may vary based on the OS since different os stores temp files differently